# A container of objects with shared_ptr members; another container with copies of those pointers in a different order; How to remove without destroying

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, shared-ptr

**EDIT:** I've changed this to use std::shared_ptr in both containers and also specified a virtual destructor for the base class.
It still crashes the instant it tries to dereference the `std::list<std::shared_ptr<MidiMessage>>::iterator` .

```
class MidiMessage {
    uint32 id;
    uint8 noteNumber;
};
    
class NoteOn : public MidiMessage {
    uint8 byte1 = 144;
};
    
class NoteOff : public MidiMessage {
    uint8 byte1 = 128;
};
    
class Note {
    uint32 id;
    std::shared_ptr<NoteOn> noteOn;
    std::shared_ptr<NoteOff> noteOff;
};
    
std::vector<Note> score;
std::list<MidiMessage*> midiScore;
```

I have something to this effect.

The notes are in one order, and they have unique IDs. The `NoteOn` and `NoteOff` messages are in a different order, also because the times and durations can be modified after creation, so their order can change. Thus they need to be stored in a different list. But the `Note` object has pointers to them so it can change their other attributes without iterating through the list of `MidiMessage`s.

Everything works just fine, except for removing items from `midiScore`. All of the options for `std::list` also call the destructor of the item itself. I think that's the problem; I'm getting no feedback whatsoever from the program, it simply exits without a trace.

I can splice those pointers into another "deleted" list, in case the delete action is undone; but if the user runs undo on the action of adding the `Note`, the `Note` itself is completely deleted. Then, it either destroys the `shared_ptr`, while a reference still exists in the list, or it removes it from the list, which attempts to run a destructor.

Overall, I think I don't understand `shared_ptr`, which apparently can't actually be shared... but my question is whether it's possible to remove a pointer from any container without destroying it.

Comment: The list should store `std::shared_ptr<MidiMessage>` as well. `MidiMessage` should have a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: They are shared in the sense that they only copy the pointer to the object, not the object itself, and will only destroy the object when the last copy is destroyed.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for the tip. Neither of these changes stops it from crashing, but I've implemented both.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard You need to form a [mre]. The issue is somewhere in the details of how you are operating with these pointers. With the changes I suggested there is nothing conceptually wrong with the approach.

Comment: I weaseled out my mistake, and it is totally unrelated.
Hidden in the constructor of a class that contained this one was an unchecked vector dereference that occurred before the vector was filled. It was only crashing because of the attempt to read a value from an empty vector.
I believe I should delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

> All of the options for `std::list` also call the destructor of the item itself. I think that's the problem

Your `std::list` contains raw pointers, which don't have destructors.  Removing a raw pointer from a `std::list` (or any container) does nothing to the object that is being pointed at.  So that is not the problem.

The real problem is more likely due to your `std::list` holding raw pointers to begin with, instead of holding `std::shared_ptr<MidiMessage>` objects, so that `Note::noteOn` and `Note::noteOff` can *properly* share object pointers that are also stored in `midiScore`.

> I'm getting no feedback whatsoever from the program, it simply exits without a trace.

That is usually a sign of undefined behavior or memory corruption.

> Overall, I think I don't understand `shared_ptr`, which apparently can't actually be shared...

Yes, it can.  You just aren't sharing it *enough*.

> my question is whether it's possible to remove a pointer from any container without destroying it.

A raw pointer, yes.  A smart pointer, no.

If your `std::list` were holding `std::shared_ptr<MidiMessage>` objects, then their reference counts would apply, and your `MidiMessage` objects would not be destroyed until **all** `shared_ptr`s pointing at them were destroyed.

Comment: That makes sense, but because it makes sense, I've already tried it. That isn't the problem either, then, because it still just stops cold. I have an iterator to the list of shared ptrs, and when it finds one that matches the id, any attempt to dereference it crashes.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard That means you are no managing your pointers correctly. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action.